# How to get id from response and verify OTP in Javascript

Tags: javascript, api

I am working with simple HTML and JS code to create a OTP verification form and when user submit the email he will receive an otp and to get verified we need to take id from response.

**Here is my response JSON:-**

```
{
    "createdBy": null,
    "createdAt": "2022-08-20 18:31:14",
    "lastModifiedBy": null,
    "lastModifiedAt": "2022-08-20 18:31:14",
    "id": "huuhby667-4124-41e1-7gt6-t7thgfy7t",
    "username": null,
    "email": "username@gmail.com",
    "phoneNumber": null,
    "countryCode": null,
    "isEmailVerified": false,
}
```

**Here is my Email Code:-**

```
const emailForm = document.getElementById('email-form');
      if(!!emailForm) {
        emailForm.addEventListener('submit',  function(e) { 
          e.preventDefault();
          const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        const response =  fetch('api-email-link', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ email: email }),
      }).then(function(response){
        return response.json()}).then(function(data){
          console.log(data)
           document.getElementById('verify-modal-background').style.display = "flex";
        }).catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
        });
      };
```

**Here is My OTP Verification Code:-**

```
   const inputOtp = document.getElementById("otp-input-form");
    const id = JSON.parse(response.id);
    inputOtp.addEventListener('submit', async function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
      let inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("otp-input-box");
      let referralCodeInput = document.getElementById("referral-input").value;
      let getOtpInput = [];
      for (let i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
       getOtpInput.push(inputs[i].value);
      }
      const data = {
        otp: getOtpInput
      };
      const response = await fetch(`https://otp-verification/api/auth/${id}/register-email`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

I'm trying this but unable to get the ID properly so i can verify this otp for the particular register email.